# Bootstrap SideBar (Template) : I want the navbar in the content to stretch even without long paragraph beneath

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, sidebar

I follow a tutorial online to create a delicious looking sidebar: 
 https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  margin: 40px 0;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.945, 0.020, 0.270, 0.665);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -250px;
  transform: rotateY(100deg);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before,
a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '\e259';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '\e260';
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebarCollapse {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

#sidebarCollapse span {
  width: 80%;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background: #555;
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.810, -0.330, 0.345, 1.375);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

#sidebarCollapse span:first-of-type {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
}

#sidebarCollapse span:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#sidebarCollapse span:last-of-type {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(1px, -1px);
}

#sidebarCollapse.active span {
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 5px auto;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0;
    transform: none;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span:first-of-type,
  #sidebarCollapse span:nth-of-type(2),
  #sidebarCollapse span:last-of-type {
    transform: none;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 5px auto;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse.active span {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse.active span:first-of-type {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
  }
  #sidebarCollapse.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse.active span:last-of-type {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(1px, -1px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- Import bootstrap 4 styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>THE BIN | List All Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <h3>THE BIN</h3>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <p>MARK</p>
        <li>
          <a href="account.php">Account</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="listAllBin.php">List All Bin</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="listFullBin.php">List Full Bin</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="content">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="navbar-toggler">
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                        </button>
          </div>

          <span class="navbar-text"><h4>List All Bin</h4></span>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <p class="d-none d-md-block">
        This page list all of the bin you would like to monitor. Bin ID uniquely identifies each of the bin, the Description tells details of the bin such as location and etc.
      </p>

      <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Bin ID</th>
          <th>Bin Description</th>
          <th>Bin Capacity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Block A</td>
          <td>80%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Block B</td>
          <td>80%</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Import bootstrap 4 scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

It totally looks awesome and I changed here and there as I used bootstrap 4 while the tutorial used bootstrap 3. But this does not explain why the navbar does not stretch to the right. I even hid the paragraph on small devices to make it look better but it still looks ugly on medium devices. Please! Laziness has overtook my body. Learning bootstrap from scratch is too painful. Still, getting this far makes me so proud of myself. For those still oblivious of what I'm talking, take a look at the pictures I've attached.

[Large Device - Yayy beautiful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScJba.png)

[Small Device - Umm Sexy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRIAp.png)

[Medium Device - WHAT THE FISH is happening?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVKod.png)

P/S: I know I know... the small device is a cheat. The navbar does not stretch at all. It need its precious long text in order to stretch.

Comment: *"Laziness has overtook my body."* -- Really?

Comment: Please ask clear and concise questions, and cut the other crap. Please see this post on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: hahaha my eyes is throbbing for staring at computer screen non-stop. it's not healthy you know? i need to be in zen mode~~

Comment: Ahh okay... thank you @spikespaz im reading it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `div#content` is a direct child of `div#wrapper` it is not behaving as block elements normally would. `div#wrapper` has a CSS property of `display: flex` which means you need to specify widths for its children for consistent behavior.

Adding a width CSS rule to `div#content` should fix your problem.

```
#content { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Yeay!! Thank you very much!! I tried that before but maybe I overlook or misplace it...